# validate file content with bash Regular Expressions

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, regular-expression

How to validate the following file content?

That should be include single integer/float number by bash Regular Expression or any other idea with awk/sed.

example:

```
cat  /var/VERSION/Version_F35_project_usa
2.8
```

Comment: You want to validate that is says "2.8"?

Comment: no this example num , any float or integer number

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.  You want to validate that the file only contains a number?  Validate means to prove that something is true.  What do you want to check for?  The existence of a number or the existence of 2.8?

Comment: Do you want any float (like 1.2e-2, -1, 0x9.d7p-3) or just the `1.2`, `-1.2` variations? Or something that looks more like a version number like 1.2.3, 1.2pre2, 1.2-3, 12.2a... Should the locale's decimal separator (`.` or `,`) be honoured?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `grep`, if matched means that's valid:

```
grep -P '^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$' infile.txt
```

The above regex can be used in `sed` or `awk` or any command.

```
sed -n -Ee '/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/p'
```

```
awk '/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/'
```

Here is also checking if file match with this regex or not.

```
awk '/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/{print "matched";exit} {print "not-matched";exit}' file
```

Comment: The [1-9]+ fails to match `104.23`, as `0.0`, also `0.` and plain `0`.

Comment: Hi @Arrow, This will match as your desired one `'^[0-9]+\.?([0-9]+)?$' `, by the way I don't think so `x.` is considering valid by OP's question even in [edit history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/386057/3) I did this but I fixed to don't match `x. `

Comment: Technically, those check if any line in the file (only the first for the last one) match the pattern, not the file as a whole.

Comment: Note that there's nothing `perl` specific in the first `grep` one, so you could do `grep -xE '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?'` to make it standard/portable. See also `sed '/^[0-9]\{1,\}\(\.[0-9]\{1,\}\)\{0,1\}$/!d'` for a standard/portable equivalent of your `sed` one.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to check that the file as a whole contains a number of decimal digits, optionally followed by a `.` and more digits and then an optional newline character, you could do:

```
is_valid() {
   awk 'END{exit(!(NR == 1 && /^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/))}' < "$1"
}

if is_valid /var/VERSION/Version_F35_project_usa; then
  echo the file has the right kind of content
else
  echo >&2 the file does not have the right kind of content
fi
```

Comment: This is interesting. Can you explain a bit about $1 part and >&2 part?The way I understand it is, it looks for x.x type number and stores it as variable $1. Then if $1 exists then print true statement, else print no right content.

Comment: This doesn't allow `+2` or `-25`, rejects `   1.3` and accepts as valid `0000.00`. Not to mention `1,345,234.75434`,  `1.345.234,75434` or `1e3`.

Comment: @Arrow. Indeed. But it specifies exactly what it matches and the OP didn't answer when I asked what floats they wanted be matched (see comments on the question). If you want to nitpick, you might argue that with some `awk` implementations it could give false positives on things like `1<NUL>whatever`.

Comment: The question do state *single integer/float number*. AFAICT `+25` is an integer, as is `1e3` and `   1.3` seems to me to match *a float*. So: no, your regex does not match what was asked, only a limited solution to some parcial view of the problem.